# SQLite with React Native error 'table xxxx has no column yyyy'

Tags: sqlite, react-native, expo

I was testing SQLite in React Native, I'm using expo, so the package I'm using is expo-sqlite, so here is my code, is very simple because is for testing:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite'

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('test')

export default function App() {

    testDB()

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Wello Horld!</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

async function testDB() {
    await db.transaction(async tx => {
        console.log('on transaction')
        await tx.executeSql(
            'create table if not exists tasks (id integer primary key autoincrement, content text );',
            [],
            (tx, result) => console.log('result on create: ', result),
            (tx, err) => console.log('error on create:', err)
        )
        await tx.executeSql(
            'insert into tasks (content) values (?)',
            ['testing'],
            (tx, result) => console.log('result on insert: ', result),
            (tx, err) => console.log('error on insert: ', err)
        )
         await tx.executeSql(
            'select * from tasks',
            [],
            (tx, result) => console.log('result on select: ', result),
            (tx, err) => console.log('error on select: ', error)
        )
    })
}
```

the output:

```
result on create:  WebSQLResultSet {
  "insertId": 0,
  "rows": WebSQLRows {
    "_array": Array [],
    "length": 0,
  },
  "rowsAffected": 0,
}
error on insert:  [Error: table tasks has no column named content (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , 
while compiling: insert into tasks (content) values (?)]
result on select:  WebSQLResultSet {
  "insertId": undefined,
  "rows": WebSQLRows {
    "_array": Array [],
    "length": 0,
  },
  "rowsAffected": 0,
}
```

Why the column is not being created when the first executeSQL method is called? I've watched some examples and the way of creating the table is always the same.

Comment: Could an earlier version of the table `tasks` exist _without_ the column `content`?

Comment: nope, that is all the code, I'm gonna try the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `db.transaction` does not work like most of programmers would expect it to work - it does not support passing `async` function or function that returns a promise or anything like that and `tx.executeSql` just ["Enqueues a SQL statement to execute in the transaction"](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/).

Related links with some info on subject: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1889, https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/3726, https://forums.expo.io/t/are-expo-sqlite-transactions-sync-or-async/7934/5

In order to utilize transactions, you can use `db.exec` with `begin transaction`/`commit`/`rollback` SQL statements. You need separate connection for transaction. I use my own [wrapper](https://blog.gennady.pp.ua/wrapper-for-expo-sqlite-with-async-await-migrations-and-transactions-support/) for that

Comment: i have some issue with sqlite, i create the insert fetch delete functions and for some  reason it doesn't work for me. can you help me please ?